# Spree eCommerce Stripe Payment gateway error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, stripe-payments

I'm working on Spree and trying to integrate Stripe as a payment method. I'm getting following Error at spree Confirm state.

```
--- !ruby/object:ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response
params:
error:
type: invalid_request_error
message: You must supply either a card or a customer id
message: You must supply either a card or a customer id 
success: false
test: false
authorization: 
fraud_review: 
avs_result:
code: 
message: 
street_match: 
postal_match: 
cvv_result:
code: 
message:
```

Any help would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the stripe gateway provided by the spree_gateway project?

Comment: yep. i'm using Stripe provided by spree_gate_way project.